# CodeDeploy does not deploy to new ASG group because of CloudFormation resources creation order

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-code-deploy

I am trying to develop an entire AWS architecture by usin CloudFormation only, however I am having some issues with the integration of CodeDeploy with CloudFormation and AutoScaling Group.

The problem is that, since I need to associate the CodeDeploy DeploymentGroup to an AutoScaling Group in order for the auto-deployment to work, CloudFormation recognizes the group as being required before creating the deployment group.

What happens is that the ASG gets created, instances start to spin up BEFORE the deployment group has been created, which means that these instances will never get deployed. I tried to think of a Lambda function to forcefully deploy these instances, however the problems persists because the CodeDeploy Deployment Group will still not be available yet most likely, or if it was,  it's not reliable.

This problem only occurs when the stack is created for the first time.

This is my CloudFormation template:

```yaml
[...]

UpdateApiAutoscalingGroup:
  Type: AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup
  Properties:
    AutoScalingGroupName:
      Fn::Join:
        - ''
        - - !ImportValue UpdateApiCodeDeployApplication
          - -autoscaling-group
          - !Ref Environment
    DesiredCapacity: !Ref MinimumApiAmount
    HealthCheckGracePeriod: 30
    HealthCheckType: ELB
    LaunchConfigurationName: !Ref UpdateApiAutoscalingLaunchConfiguration
    TargetGroupARNs:
      - !Ref UpdateApiTargetGroup
    MaxSize: !Ref MaximumApiAmount
    MinSize: !Ref MinimumApiAmount
    VPCZoneIdentifier:
      - Fn::Select:
        - 0
        - !Split
          - ","
          - Fn::ImportValue:
              !Sub "PrivateSubnets-${Environment}"
    Tags:
      - Key: Environment
        Value: !Ref Environment
        PropagateAtLaunch: true
      - Key: CompanySshAccess
        Value: 1
        PropagateAtLaunch: true
      - Key: Application
        Value: update-api
        PropagateAtLaunch: true

# Defines how the Update API servers should be provisioned in the scaling group.
UpdateApiAutoscalingLaunchConfiguration:
  Type: AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration
  Properties:
    AssociatePublicIpAddress: false
    IamInstanceProfile: !Ref UpdateApiInstanceRole
    ImageId: !FindInMap [Api, Image, !Ref Environment]
    InstanceType: !FindInMap [Api, InstanceType, !Ref Environment]
    LaunchConfigurationName: !Sub 'update-api-launchconfig-${Environment}'
    SecurityGroups:
      - Fn::ImportValue: !Sub 'InternalBastionSecurityGroupId-${Environment}'
      - !GetAtt LoadBalancerProtectedSecurityGroup.GroupId

UpdateApiCodeDeploymentGroup:
  Type: AWS::CodeDeploy::DeploymentGroup
  Properties:
    DeploymentGroupName: !Ref Environment
    DeploymentConfigName: "atleast-one-instance-online"
    ServiceRoleArn: !Ref CodeDeployServiceRoleArn # TODO: create CodeDeployServiceRole using CloudFormation
    ApplicationName: !ImportValue UpdateApiCodeDeployApplication
    LoadBalancerInfo:
      ElbInfoList:
        - Name: !GetAtt UpdateApiLoadBalancer.LoadBalancerName
    DeploymentStyle:
      DeploymentOption: !FindInMap [Api, DeploymentStyleOption, !Ref Environment]
      DeploymentType: !FindInMap [Api, DeploymentStyleType, !Ref Environment]
    AutoScalingGroups:
      - !Ref UpdateApiAutoscalingGroup

[...]
```

Comment: I've taking a pass before at using just cloudformation and AWS devops services to manange infrastructure and it has never worked out for reasons like this.  Still waiting for someone to announce success.  I am intending to try AWS CodeStar to see if it helps.